# How to reset the property Text of TextBox from template ? Only in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textbox style with button to clear value of textbox,
but when the event click on button, the value disappear and reappear when release the    button mouse.
below the xaml code:

```
<ResourceDictionary .....

<Style x:Key="SearchBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
 <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="8.6*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="1.4*" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBox Background="Transparent" x:Name="searchTextBox" Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0"
               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
       <Button Background="Transparent" 
               x:Name="clearButton"  Content="X"
               Margin="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
               Grid.Column="1"/>
      </Grid>
     </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <Trigger SourceName="clearButton"  Property="IsPressed"  Value="True" >
         <Setter TargetName="searchTextBox" Property="TextBox.Text" Value="" />
     </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use like:

```
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxTemplate}"  
             Width="200"
             Text="{Binding SearchLastName, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    Mode=TwoWay}" />

// C# SearchViewModel 

internal class SearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
 private string _searchLastName; 

 public string SearchLastName
 {
     get { return this._searchLastName; }
     set
     {
         this._searchLastName = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("SearchLastName");
     }
 }
 ......
```

How, and is it possible?
someone can help me?

Regards

Comment: Is your goal to clear the bound property, or are you just trying to alter the text which displays on the control?

Comment: Both, I think if one is removed the other also !!!
This is not true?

Answer (score 1):

Triggers will automatically perform operations for IsPressed="False". Write a trigger that listens for IsPressed="False".

Updated answer:

```
<Style x:Key="SearchBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8.6*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.4*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBox Background="Transparent" x:Name="searchTextBox" Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0"

                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                                        <Button Background="Transparent" 
               x:Name="clearButton"  Content="X"
               Margin="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
               Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger SourceName="clearButton"  Property="IsPressed"  Value="True" >
                                    <Setter TargetName="searchTextBox" Property="Text" Value="" />
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

<TextBox  Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxTemplate}"
             Width="200"
             Text="{Binding SearchLastName,Mode=TwoWay,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged 
                    }" />
```

ViewModel:

```
internal class SearchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string _searchLastName=string.Empty;

        public string SearchLastName
        {
            get { return _searchLastName; }
            set
            {
                _searchLastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SearchLastName");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've tried both IsPressed false and true and not work.
When I type in textbox the property in viewModel is not changed and event onpropertyChanged not fire.

Comment: You solution clear well the text but in SearchViewModel not update event fire :(  
When I type a text, SearchLastName is not updated.    
When I click on clear button, SearchLastName is not updated also.

Comment: You can override the TextBox style with delete button. Default style is in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do this in quite the way you're atttempting (although I could be wrong).

My understanding is that in the first instance (before the button is pressed), your `TextBox` named `searchTextBox` will be obtaining its value from the `Path` specified in the `ParentTemplate`, the `TextBox.Text` property - which is bound to your local `SearchLastName` property.

When you press the button, you're overriding the binding which has been set on the `searchTextBox` control, so that the value of `TextBox.Text` is no longer obtained from the bound `Path` to `SearchLastName`, it is instead simply set to the empty string literal `""`, which is what you see displayed (set from your `ParentTemplateTrigger`).

Once the button is released, the binding reverts back to the previous `Path` to your property, which has never been changed, and will remain the same.

If you want to actually the clear the `SearchLastName` property, you'll either have to make the button fire a command/action which clears your search, or manipulate `Text` property of the control (which I believe there are ways to do entirely within the UI with relative bindings, but it may be a tricky solution for a simple problem). I don't believe you'll be able to do it with switching templates.

Comment: Yes this is what seems to happen :(

Answer (score 0):

**First** issue is you are missing `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` on TextBox inside template. Default value for TextBox is `LostFocus`. You need to set it to `PropertyChanged` in case you want source property to be updated while typing in textBox.

```
<TextBox Background="Transparent" x:Name="searchTextBox" Grid.Column="0"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0"
         Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                   Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
```

**Second**, you have used `Trigger` on `IsPressed` value of button. So, it will revert once `IsPressed` value gets reversed. `IsPressed` state is transient, you need to update the bound property on `Click` event which you can achieve via `EventTrigger` but sadly it cannot have setter inside.

So, you should change the `Text` by binding it to `ICommand` in ViewModel and simply set the underlying bound property from command method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with your comments I did this:

In SearchviewModel

```
    .....
    private ICommand clearCommand;
    public ICommand ClearCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.clearCommand == null)
                this.clearCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.ClearSearch(), ()=> CanSearch());

            return this.clearCommand;
        }
    }

    void ClearSearch()
    {
        Search = string.Empty;
    }

    bool CanSearch()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_search);
    }
    .....
```

In style

```
 <Style....
  <Button
    ....
    Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
 </Style>
```

And I have removed Trigger

It's Work fine, but I wanted the pure xaml.

Many thanks to all :)

Best regards

Comment: But you still need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` in case you want source property to be updated as soon as typing in textBox instead of lostFocus.

Comment: I did it, you can see in my first post above :)

Comment: I meant for the textBox inside template i.e. `searchTextBox`, not on the outer one..